# Gradle sync Failed : Operation Timed out

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I opened my android studio today and the Gradle will not sync!

I get the errors below :
[image]

Studio Version :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: not that I know of @RahulKumar

Comment: did you try @wilddev soultion

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop gradle daemon `gradle --stop` or `gradlew --stop`

Comment: @AndroidKrayze where gradlew.bat(on windows) or gradlew file (linux and macos) is locatied. (It's actually the root of tour android application project)

Comment: I went int the directory and command not found : look image for link : http://imgur.com/a/KKbGz

Comment: @AndroidKrayze just run `./gradlew --stop` (note ./ at the beginning)

Comment: so I typed ./gradlew -- stop and I got Permission denied. So next i typed sudo ./gradlew --stop and I got command not found.

Comment: You don't need to use sudo. Try adding execution rights for gradlew file: `chmod +x gradlew` and then run `./gradlew --stop`

Comment: so now that i stopped Gradle Daemon i get this : Error:(23, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AndroidLoginAndRegistration2'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_actsom3yy0k4yckhwgzi1tao3$_run_closure2@764db8ae] on root project 'AndroidLoginAndRegistration2' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Do i have to re-enable gradle daemon or that is done automatically when ypu compile project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137149/discussion-between-wilddev-and-androidkrayze).

Comment: ey Managed to fix it. So basically someone from the department changed the DNS on the router. Now i could not connect to maven central. Now changing DNS settings also can mess up the build.gradle config by adding unnecessary code! I appreciate your help guys.. and btw NEVER CHANGE YOUR DNS!